# Highlighting text c#

Tags: c#, colors, formatting

I currently have a program that is a dice rolling game. 7 Dice are rolled and my program checks for different matches for example a three of a kind. Is there any way to highlight the numbers that are the three of a kind using formatting? So that the numbers that are in the three of a kind are highlighted in red?

Much Appreciated

Code:

```
var duplicates = diceValues
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        .Where(g => g.Count() == 3)
        .Select(g => g.Key);
        foreach (var d in duplicates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0} Appeared three times --- 3 Points Awarded\n", d);
            threepoints += 3;
        }
```

Comment: You need to define colors and then write to the current line. See https://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with string formatting, as it's a UI thing. You could however use the `BackgroundColor` property of the console to highlight your text:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write("\n{0}", d);
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
Console.WriteLine(" Appeared three times --- 3 Points Awarded\n");
```

You could of course write yourself a function that does this in a string formatting like way:

```
public static void WriteColoredLine(string formattedString, params object[] pars)
{
    var pattern = "[{]\\d[}]";
    var splitted = Regex.Split(formattedString, pattern);
    var formatItems = Regex.Matches(formattedString, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value.Trim('{', '}'))).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < splitted.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(splitted[i]);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write(pars[formatItems[i]]);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(splitted.Last());
}
```

If you want the color specified as well, you could use a value tuple for your pars:

```
public static void WriteColoredLine(string formattedString, params (object, ConsoleColor)[] pars)
{
    var pattern = "[{]\\d[}]";
    var splitted = Regex.Split(formattedString, pattern);
    var formatItems = Regex.Matches(formattedString, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value.Trim('{', '}'))).ToList();
    for (var i = 0; i < splitted.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(splitted[i]);
        Console.BackgroundColor = pars[formatItems[i]].Item2;
        Console.Write(pars[formatItems[i]].Item1);
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(splitted.Last());
}
```

Remember to install the `ValueTuple` type from NuGet, if you don't target the newest .Net version.

This method is called like that:

```
WriteColoredLine("\n{0} Appeared three times --- 3 Points Awarded\n", ("foo", ConsoleColor.Red));
```